# Basic HTML/CSS relative font size issue

Tags: html, css, browser

Please consider the following MRE for a simultaneous super & sub-script block unit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<style>
#mainwin { display: inline-block; width: 94%; margin: 0 auto 4em auto; padding: 0 0.8em 2em 0.8em; }
#ud { position: relative; display: inline; }
#u { position: absolute; display: inline; font-size: 0.7em; bottom: 1em; }
#d { position: relative; display: inline; font-size: 0.7em; top: 0.6em; }
</style>
<body>
<div id="mainwin">
<p style="margin-left:1em;">integral<span id="ud"><span id="u">44</span><span id="d">5</span></span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem here is that if I were to host this code in an *embedded* container like WebView2 or CEF, the font sizes adhere to the given proportions.

MS Edge and Firefox as browsers will not adhere to the font-size rules, and the acting sub and super script spans will have roughly the same font size as everything else. Behavior persists even if I have explicitly set the font size of at least one prior parent container and `body`.

What is going on here?
If I use `px` instead of `em`, it won't even register a change.
This leads me to believe I have missed to set something along the component tree.

If something is indeed wrong, what causes embedded instances to appear to be fine?

Please advise,

Comment: please keep the html and meta tags in the code. they seem to matter as to how the code is behaving. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set font size in p element in px?
In that case the em font size will be relative to parent font size

```css
#mainwin {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0 auto 4em auto;
  padding: 0 0.8em 2em 0.8em;
}

#parent {
  font-size: 16px; /* <---- here! */
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#ud {
  position: relative; display: inline;
}

#u {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  bottom: 1em;
}

#d {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  top: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwin">
  <p id="parent">integral<span id="ud"><span id="u">44</span><span id="d">5</span></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: oh wow! you're right; i was assuming ```<p>``` would inherit from ```<body>``` unless specified - but i'll keep this in mind! weird how the embedded browser was going along with it though... anyway, thank you!

Comment: Anytime!, glad to help :D